# What is a stream-url?

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, dom, google-chrome-extension

When looking at pdfs in google chrome, the structure of the DOM is very similar. There is always an embed element with a 'stream-url' attribute with a value like this: 'blob:chrome-extension://abunchofrandomnumbersandletterswithdashes'

For example:

Excerpt from: http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/95301F67-C250-4082-B5C0-6BDBB077B63C" headers="Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 111906
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 03:53:17 GMT
ETag: &quot;1b522-4e738e204e8c0&quot;
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 17:50:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" full-frame="">
```

The only thing I've noticed is the value does change if you re-open the tab. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Type `chrome://plugins` in address bar, you will find there is a plugin named "Chrome PDF Viewer", its id is `mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai`, that's it.

Answer (score -1):

> What is a stream-url?

I think a stream-url works similar like the concept of the [URL of a media stream](http://all-streaming-media.com/faq/recording-media-stream/faq-get-media-stream-URL.htm). This is where the Chrome plugin [streams your pdf file](http://www.techper.net/2008/02/27/4-ways-to-stream-pdf-and-some-tips/).